# Using python for graphics projection?

Tags: python, windows, system, projector

If this is not the best place to ask this, please advise me on an alternative exchange.

I'm trying to create a matrix (N x N) and project it onto a wall using a projector. Each cell of the matrix will have the option to be color-coded or lit. So, given a matrix and a cell, the program will be able to colorize it.

Right now I can achieve this using the `graphics.py` library and Tkinter. However, when I connect my projector to my laptop via VGA, I have to drag the Tkinter window over and position it on the extended projector screen. It's a manual drag and re-positioning and this should be all automatic.

Are there any other methods (preferably in Python) of achieving this or something similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set your laptop to mirror its screen instead of using the projector as an extended desktop. Then you won't have to drag Tkinter over. This is an OS / videocard setting and has nothing to do with Python.